# LLVM error instead of 3D acceleration in Debian stable

Tags: debian, intel, intel-graphics, llvm

I've installed Debian stable (Jessie) on a Acer Notebool (Aspire ES 15).

If I try to start some programs (qtcreator, processing) I see:

```
LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: intrinsic %llvm.x86.sse41.pblendvb
```

I think the reason is a not working 3D acceleration.(But I'm not sure)
I already installed the video-intel package with:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

but this didn't change anything (even after reboot).

```
$ sudo lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 10
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22b1] (rev 21) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:1012]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
        Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 2000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [b0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=07 <?>

$ glxinfo | grep -i opengl -A 3
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_AMD_conservative_depth, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3,
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, 

$ uname -a
Linux Bernd 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3 (2016-01-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ xdriinfo 
Screen 0: not direct rendering capable.
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by updating my kernel from 3.16 to 4.3. For Debian Jessie, the new kernel can be installed from [backports](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/):

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-4.6.0-0.bpo.1-686-pae
```

Actual image name will depend on what kind of hardware you have and what kernel flavour you prefer.

Comment: wellcome to U&L SE, maybe you can give more details ?

Comment: Yes, please include the command(s) you ran to upgrade.

Comment: I had a similar issue and can confirm that upgrading the kernel does solve it.

Comment: Note that, depending on your needs, you may also want to install other backports packages. For example, I needed to install `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and restart Xorg to bid adieu to the lvvm complaint...

Answer (score 0):

I am no Linux connoisseur, but to me installing libgl1-mesa-swx11 did at least part of the trick : 3d functionalities now seem to work.

(note : libgl1-mesa-glx was suppressed at the installation of libgl1-mesa-swx11)

Comment: The downvotes are probably because (and I just tried this so I can confirm) swx11 means it's implementing mesa (ie openGL's api) in software (ie not the graphics card), so the framerate is too low for any practical use.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue today, fresh Debian Jessie with the Intel graphical chipset that's in the Celeron N3050 ; I found this question and answer. Unfortunately upgrading the Kernel did not help. However, upgrading all of the following packages from jessie-backports did solve the issue :

```
libegl1-mesa
libegl1-mesa-drivers
libgl1-mesa-dri
libgl1-mesa-glx
libglapi-mesa
libgles1-mesa
libgles2-mesa
libglu1-mesa
libopenvg1-mesa
libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0
libwayland-egl1-mesa
mesa-utils
mesa-utils-extra
libva-drm1
```