# Intel Braswell Integrated Graphics on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, xrandr, intel

I'm having trouble getting Jessie to use the integrated graphics on a Celeron N3050 (Braswell).

I've tried installing xserver-xorg-video-intel from jessie-backports but this doesn't help.

`glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"`
output:

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

`lspci -vnn`
output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2280] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:80c5]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device      [8086:22b1] (rev 21) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:80c5]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:0b.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22dc] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:80c5]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at 91514000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:13.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22a3] (rev 21) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:80c5]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 131
    I/O ports at 2060 [size=32]
    Memory at 91515000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22b5] (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:80c5]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133
    Memory at 91500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:1a.0 Encryption controller [1080]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2298] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:80c5]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at 91400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at 91300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2284] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:80c5]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 134
    Memory at 91510000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22c8] (rev 21) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: 91600000-917fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000091800000-00000000919fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22cc] (rev 21) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: 91200000-912fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22ce] (rev 21) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
    Memory behind bridge: 91100000-911fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000091000000-00000000910fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:229c] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:80c5]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2292] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:80c5]
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 7
    Memory at 91516000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
    I/O ports at 2040 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804a]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at 91200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:80c5]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 132
    I/O ports at 1000 [size=256]
    Memory at 91100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

The root issue I'm having is that `xrandr` can't identify the gamma, and thus can't set the output device parameters (the one that I'm mainly interested in is **brightness**).

Answer (score 1):

Having just come across the problem myself (same issues, similar hardware and outputs you quote here), I struggled with a variety of tweaks and Xorg configs with no luck until I found that the only fix that worked for me was updating my kernel from 3.16 to 4.9 through the Jessie backports:

```
sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
```

In my troubleshooting, having returned the same error from glxgears as found in [this SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260591/llvm-error-instead-of-3d-acceleration-in-debian-stable), I tried the libraries suggested in the [2nd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324706/231358) solution which fixed the 3D graphics errors alone, but to get full controll over the display and return functionality to xrandr, xbacklight, etc, the kernel upgrade was necessary. Display/backlight associated things worked out of the box from there, including backlight media keys.